# Populating 2 listbox with diferent rows

Tags: vba, excel, filter, listbox

i have 1 combobox and 2 listbox on my userform:

1. `cbox_rrhh`
2. `lbox_por`
3. `lbox_done`

[image]

and a sheet "Pedidos" like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I found a way to filter the listbox data following the combobox value which is the one at the "J" column ex(roraima,karla,yvonne,sara) but i also need the rows be shown on `lbox_por` if the column "J" matches "Si" if is "NO" got to load those rows in the `lbox_done`".

Code used:

```
    Private Sub cbo_rrhh_Change()
Dim Cell As Range                   'defining your searcharea
Dim Row_Counter As Integer          'rowno
Dim Pos As Integer                  'rowno in array
Dim MyList() As String              'the array
Dim No_Pos As Integer               'total rows in aray
Dim Search_name As String           'searchvalue in combobox
Dim Real_last_row As Integer        'last row in "Pedidos"

'xllastrow is a function

Real_last_row = xlLastRow("Pedidos") 'last row in "Pedidos"

Search_name = cbo_rrhh.Value

'Searching in "Pedidos" for matches with searchstring

For Each Cell In Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("J2:J" & Real_last_row)
    If Cell Like "*" & Search_name & "*" Then
'If a value matches with the searchstring, number of rows of array is + 1
        No_Pos = No_Pos + 1
    End If
Next Cell

Row_Counter = 2                  'start of the nameslist
Pos = 0                          'rowno in array, beginning with zero
ReDim Preserve MyList(No_Pos, 8) 'Redimming of array with total no of rows and 3 columns

'if value isn't in searchstring then rowno is rowno + 1
'if a match is found the array is filled and the rowno in array is + 1

For Each Cell In Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("J2:J" & Real_last_row)
    If Cell Like "*" & Search_name & "*" Then
        MyList(Pos, 0) = Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("A" & Row_Counter)
        MyList(Pos, 1) = Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("B" & Row_Counter)
        MyList(Pos, 2) = Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("C" & Row_Counter)
        MyList(Pos, 3) = Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("E" & Row_Counter)
        MyList(Pos, 4) = Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("F" & Row_Counter)
        MyList(Pos, 5) = Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("G" & Row_Counter)
        MyList(Pos, 6) = Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("H" & Row_Counter)
        MyList(Pos, 7) = Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("I" & Row_Counter)
        MyList(Pos, 8) = Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("J" & Row_Counter)
        Pos = Pos + 1
        Row_Counter = Row_Counter + 1
    Else
        Row_Counter = Row_Counter + 1
    End If
Next Cell
Application.ShowToolTips = True

With lbox_por
    .ColumnCount = 10                           'no of columns (0,1,2)
    .ControlTipText = "Pedidos pendientes ..."    'tiptext

End With
With lbox_done
    .ColumnCount = 9                           'no of columns (0,1,2)
    .ControlTipText = "Pedidos realizados ..."    'tiptext

End With
lbox_por.List = MyList                          'define the list of listbox1
lbox_done.List = MyList

End Sub
```

and for context:
Fecha: means Date.
Palabras: Words.
Tasa: Rate.
Monto: Amount.
Pagado: Paid out.
Redactor: Writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the one list box (`lbox_done`), couldn't you change:

```
If Cell Like "*" & Search_name & "*" Then
```

line to this:

```
If Cell Like "*" & Search_name & "*" And Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("I" & Row_Counter) = "NO" Then
```

And you can then create a duplicate list (i.e. `MyList2`) with the conditions changed to this:

```
If Cell Like "*" & Search_name & "*" And Worksheets("Pedidos").Range("I" & Row_Counter) = "SI" Then
```

which you could assign to the other list box -- `lbox_por`.